# Count duplicate values in a multidimentional Array

Tags: mysql, sorting

I don't think this is a duplicate because it deals with an object that has multiple record sets, although it is very similar, my needs require more loops i think. Either way, I can't seem to make it work for me. I'm just learning here and this is too complex for me. I need some examples using an object like this one. I've tried using some similar question-answers but always fail due to the extra level of loops needed.

My current code outputs a simple unsorted list:

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    if (data[i]['name'])
        $("#output").append("<p>"+data[i]['entrynum']+data[i]['name']);
```

What I want is something like:

- J0hn James
- Fr3d
- S@m Wise
- Fr3d
- Fr3d
- S@m Wise
- Fr3d
- Fred
- S@m Wise
- S@m Wise
- Frank
- Frank
- Bill
- Frank
- Bill

to output a list that reports (preferably in order desc):

- 5 Fr3d
- 4 S@m Wise
- 3 Frank
- 2 Bill
- 1 J0hn James

Comment: What is a "multi-record JSON object"? There is no such thing as a "JSON object", and neither JSON nor JavaScript have "records" or "record sets".

Comment: Put an example of the object into your question.

Comment: Probably SO is not the best environment for your kind of question. I'd suggest finding a pay-by-the-hour consulting service that could walk you through everything.

Comment: multidimensional array "row": [
        {
        "entrynum": "5",
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "street": "mystreet",
        "city": "mycity",
        "state": "mystate",
        "zipcode": "123456"}
    ]

Comment: Your JSON is actually a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned much over the night!
Here's what I have now:

```
//convert my multidimensional object into a simple list
var clublist = [];
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    if (data[i]['club']) 
        clublist.push(data[i]['club']);

//counting, converted into object with occurrence & count
var counts = {};
clublist.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });

//converted into an array to be sorted
var clubs = [];
for (var temp in counts)
    clubs.push([temp, counts[temp]])

//sorted array, descending
clubs.sort(function(a, b) { return b[1] - a[1] })

//final output to page
for (i=0; i<clubs.length; i++)
    $("#output").append("<p>"+clubs[i][1]+" - "+clubs[i][0]);
```

However, this seems like a lot of steps... any ideas on making this more compact?